# Make and reference stub object for testing, without needing the class that the stub would extend

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, stub

This is probably a simple question, I haven't been able to shorten it though.

I am testing a class of mine, `ClassToTest`. In production, it will perform operations on a third party library object, instance of `ThirdPartyClass`.

I want to mimic that class with a stub. (Using the definition of stub as used by [Martin Fowler's essay](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html): *Stubs provide canned answers to calls made during the test, usually not responding at all to anything outside what's programmed in for the test*)

The problem is:

- `ClassToTest` has a method `setThirdPartyClass(ThirdPartyClass o)`. So to pass a stub to this, the stub would have to extend `ThirdPartyClass`. This means my tests will have to use the third party library, whereas my unit test needs to be self contained.

The reason is, my code will be run on an embedded system, and the library in question mostly executes native code. But I want to develop and test my code in isolation on my PC. But I don't want to have to modify `ClassUnderTest` argument signatures and so on, for example, changing back and forth between:

```
classToTest.setThirdPartyClass(ThirdPartyClass o){ /*....*/ }
```

and

```
classToTest.setThirdPartyClass(MyThirdPartyClassStub o){ /*....*/ }
```

AFAIK, normally a stub would simply extend the class it's mimicking, so the signatures would not have to be changed (and overriding constructors etc with minimal code).

What is a good way of doing this?

Comment: can you provided an example of the method you want to test?

Comment: Use Mockito mocks instead. It uses bytecode generation to handle these issues, and you'll get a scriptable substitute for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly not the best example but essentially, using Mockito to mock the ThirdPartyClass.

`YourClass` to test

```
public class YourClass {

    private String aString;

    // Method that depends on third party component
    public void someMethod(ThirdPartyClass doc) {
        aString = doc.someStringValue();
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return aString;
    }
}
```

Test using Mockito to mock the `ThirdPartyClass` and control the value returned

```
public class YourClassTest {    

    //Class you want to test
    private YourClass testee;

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {

        testee = new YourClass(); 

        //
        // ThirdPartyClass. When the method someStringValue()
        // is called you control the value returned
        //
        ThirdPartyClass testDoc = mock(ThirdPartyClass.class);          
        when(testDoc.someStringValue()).thenReturn("aString");

        // Call method to test and pass mock as argument
        testee.someMethod(testDoc);

        // Check state of your object you want to test
        assertThat(testee.getValue(), equalTo("aString"));      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does your `ThridPartyClass` implement an interface?  If so you can change your class under test to use the interface instead of the concrete class.  Then your stub just implements the interface.

If not, there are mocking libraries such as [EasyMock](http://easymock.org) and [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) which can mock the class for you.

Using easymock for example:

```
@Test
public void test(){
   ThirdPartyClass mock = createMock(ThirdPartyClass.class);

   expect(mock.foo().andReturn("bar");
   replay(mock);

   classToTest.setThirdPartyClass(mock);
   //perform your tests on classToTest

}
```

Comment: Thank you - unfortunately it does not implement an interface; also, the tests will test the resulting state of the object under test, instead of calls the object makes - I want the tests to be independent of my code's implementation. AFAIK, mocking can only test the calls that the object makes?

Comment: Mocking the third party class allows your object to makes calls to that class which i assume collaborates to change the state of the object you want to test. You do not need to verify calls to the mock if you are not interested in indirect outputs.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of mocking (stubbing) `ThirdPartyClass`, as has been mentioned, would be if that class implements an interface, and that interface is the complete interface your `ClassToTest` uses. Then you could write a `MockThirdParty` class that `implements ThirdPartyInterface`. But I guess you can not do that.

Another option is to hide the `ThirdPartyClass` behind a `ThirdPartyFacade` class that you write.  As you write it, you can have the it implement a `ThirdPartyInterface` that you design. The methods of the `ThirdPartyFacade` class simply delegate to the `ThirdPartyClass`, so it is safe for you to do relatively little testing of that class; unit tests are not necessary for it. Alter your `ClassToTest` so it uses a reference to a `ThirdPartyInterface` object, rather than a reference to a `ThirdPartyClass` object.

You can now write a `MockThirdPartyFacade` class for testing, which `implements ThirdPartyInterface`, for testing `ClassToTest`. You can make this mock class as simple or as complicated as you tests need it to be. Different test cases could even use different mock classes; you do not need a general purpose mock class.